# Show that norm is reduced in each iteration for weighted additive orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I'm stuck in the following problem from Saad's Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems:

In an additive projection procedure, the $k+1$th residual vector is

$$\vec{r}_{k+1} = \sum_{i=1}^p w_i (I-P_i)\vec{r}_k$$

If the weights satisfy:

$$\sum_{i=1}^p w_i = 1 \ \ \ \ \ |w_i| \leq 1 \ \ \ \ \forall i$$

and the $I-P_i$ are orthogonal projectors, show that

$$||\vec{r}_{k+1}||_2 \leq ||\vec{r}_k||_2$$.

What  I tried to do was just use the triangle inequality to obtain

$$||\vec{r}_{k+1}||_2^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^p w_i^2||(I-P_i)\vec{r}_k ||_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^p w_i^2 (||\vec{r}_k||_2^2 - ||P_i\vec{r}_k||_2^2) \leq \sum_{i=1}^p w_i^2||\vec{r}_k||_2^2$$

Where the equality holds due to $(I-P_i)$ being an orthogonal projector.

My problem is that, from where I am now, it would be easy if the weights were a convex combination, but in this case they are an affine combination with the extra restriction that $|w_i| \leq 1$, and I don't know how to continue from here.

Thank you!